# Actions of G on corresponding orbits are equivalent for stable maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Given actions of $G$ on $X$ and on $Y$, these actions are equivalent if and only if there is a bijection from $X $ \ $ G \rightarrow Y$ \ $G$  so that actions of $G$ on corresponding orbits are equivalent.

Def. An action of $G$ on $X$ and $Y$ is equivalent if there is a stable bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

My Attempt at a proof

$\Rightarrow$

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is stable, then choose an $x\in X$ and let the corresponding orbit be $Gx$.  Then we have a map from the set of orbits of $X$ to the set of orbits of $Y$,

$h: X \rightarrow Y$

and

$h(Gx)=f(gx)\, \forall g\in G=g.f(x)\, \forall g\in G = h(Gy)$

thus each orbit of $X$ corresponds one to one with an orbit of $Y$.

$\Leftarrow$

Well we know each orbit of $X$ is mapped to a corresponding orbit of $Y$.  So we take the map $h$ from orbit to orbit and then we show that for each x in that orbit (since orbits are disjoint or equal) we can move the $g$'s in $G$ to outside without affecting the $y$'s.

Comment: I assume stable means the same thing as $G$-equivariant. (I also assume your *question* is for feedback on your proofs; you don't explicitly state any question.) In your $\Rightarrow$ direction you seem a bit trigger-happy with your '$\forall g\in G$'s. I can't follow what you're saying in the $\Leftarrow$ direction. When in doubt, use plain English over symbols.

Comment: Stable means $f(g.x)=g.f(x)$ for all g.  I am asking for help on the proof, yes.  
The $\Leftarrow$ is underdeveloped.  I had a few ideas going at once and wasn't careful with the editing.  I'll try to make it more concise.